# Safari cannot download passbook file .pkpass

Tags: ios, safari, passbook, wallet

I've got a link on a web page that should enable users to download a passbook file from a link, however when clicking on the link in Safari on an iPhone, I get the following error message:

```
Safari cannot download this file.
```

I have read similar Q&As on here, and the MIME type is set to `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`. The file can be downloaded on a Windows phone.

Any suggestions on why this is the case and how to resolve this so users can access the passbook file?

The pkpass contains the following files:

```
icon.png
logo.png
strip.png
manifest.json
pass.json
signature
```

An example of the manifest.json:

```
{
  "icon.png": "fa6b59072ae5c8163c903d8c8b5f2e4a45fbd49b",
  "logo.png": "3165c9be22cbf76e2b3118972dabaef8918390f5",
  "strip.png": "5d15c45f543e8088c227fc54a6c01d1f9f0b1db3",
  "pass.json": "0f536b34a6b73a7799aae43ff9861dde45a6dfc6"
}
```

An example of the pass.json:

```
{
    "passTypeIdentifier":"pass.com.XXXX.sampleticket",
    "formatVersion":1,
    "serialNumber":"TIC1000000518",
    "description":"XXXX",
    "organizationName":"XXXX",
    "teamIdentifier":"W9XR4FBDD4",
    "logoText":"Dragon Bay",
    "foregroundColor":"rgb(0,0,0)",
    "backgroundColor":"rgb(255,255,0)",
    "labelColor":"rgb(0,0,0)",
    "voided":false,
    "eventTicket":{
        "headerFields":[],
        "primaryFields":[],
        "secondaryFields":[{"key":"activity",
            "label":"11/20/2015 12:00 AM",
            "value":"One Day at the Museum"
            }],
        "auxiliaryFields":[],
        "backFields":[{
            "key":"terms",
            "label":"Terms & Conditions",
            "value":"XXXX"
        },
        {
            "key":"contact",
            "label":"XXXX",
            "value":"XXXX"
        },
        {
            "key":"legal",
            "label":"Legal",
            "value":"XXXX"
        },
        {
            "key":"notes",
            "changeMessage":"%@","label":"Notes","value":""
        },
        {
            "key":"lastUpdated",
            "label":"Last Updated",
            "dateStyle":"PKDateStyleMedium",
            "timeStyle":"PKDateStyleShort",
            "isRelative":false,
            "value":"2016-01-08T19:00Z"
        }]
    },
    "barcode":{
        "format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
        "message":"1000000518",
        "messageEncoding":"UTF-8",
        "altText":"1000000518"
    },
    "authenticationToken":"0123456789ABCDEF",
    "webServiceURL":"XXXX/passbook.svc"
}
```

Comment: It will fail on iOS because either the pass.json contains invalid values, your signature is incorrect, or the bundle is missing mandatory content.  I cannot see any obvious problems in your pass.json.  Check that your bundle contains at least an icon.png.  If you still have problems please post a link where we can download the .pkpass bundle.

Comment: also check that your `webServiceURL` protocol is `https` and the `authenticationToken` is at least 16 bytes

Comment: @PassKit The webservice is currently http

Comment: Change to https and the problem should go away!

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @PassKit Can you please elaborate more about it? what is webServiceUrl? I got issue only for the users using the edge browsers.

Comment: Edge doesn't support Apple Wallet passes - you'll need to direct them to Safari or Chrome on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the webServiceURL to use https as mentioned by @PassKit and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about it? what is webServiceUrl? I got issue only for the users using the edge browsers.

Comment: Sorry, this was over 5 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Note - I ran into this problem.  The solution for me was picking a different intermediate certificate.  Apple has TWO certificates labeled as "WWDR Certificate" in their intermediate certificates on this page: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

However, as of right now, only the one that expires in 2023 actually works for this purpose.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Spent so much time trying to figure out why it's not working. Thanks for sharing!!!

Comment: Wow. This should definitely be the selected answer. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that as 2023 is creeping up on us that this is still the answer.  Hello, Apple?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the cause for the error by viewing iPhone logs in Console.app:

1. Connect an iPhone to Mac and open Console.app on the Mac.
2. Select the iPhone in the sidebar in Console.app.
3. Click the "Start streaming" button in Console.app.
4. Open the pkpass file on the iPhone (by downloading it in Safari, open it in an email).
5. Click the "Pause" button in Console.app.
6. Search in Console.app for:

   - the pass identifier, e.g., `pass.com.example.XXXX`
   - `Pass Viewer`
   - `Invalid data`
   - `MobileSafari` (if opened in Safari)
   - `MobileMail` (if opened in Mail)

In my case, I was able to determine the error was caused by my having set the `serialNumber` value to an integer instead of a string:

```
Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.example.XXXX/(null). Value for key 'serialNumber' must be of class NSString, but is actually of class __NSCFNumber.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit old this happened to me recently so I'll just leave my solution in case it helps anyone else.

The problem on my side was that I was setting the *voided* field as a string instead of a boolean, like this: "voided":"false" and was missing the "expirationDate" field.

So doing this fixed the issue:

```
  ...
  "expirationDate": "2016-06-30T11:59:59Z",
  "voided": false,
  ...
```

It was tricky and took me a while to figure it out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had some other issue causing .pkpass files to be displayed correctly when viewed on my mac, 
but yielded the same "Safari cannot download this file" - error when trying to view them in iOS.

my source of error was:

- i was using integer values for the "key" property in the field-definitions (as i'm using a CMS to create those fields)

so, be sure to use only strings as  "key" property in the field-definitions

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you're using an up-to-date [Apple WWDR intermediate certificate](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) when creating the signature file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. caused by incorrectly entering the Hex Background color code. Logs does not always tell you the reason, basically any fields that invalid will result in iOS not accepting the pkpasses file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).